# Manutenção de código

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Tenho uma aplicação que faz a desserialização de um arquivo XML.

Eu gerei uma classe com a partir de um XSD com o XSD.EXE

Para desserialização eu uso o seguinte código:

```
static T LoadFromXMLString<T>(string xmlText)
{
    var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
}
```

Chamo ele da seguinte forma:

```
var _ProcNFe = LoadFromXMLString<ProcNFe.TNfeProc>(XmlProcNFe);
```

Após isso, uso o objeto `_ProcNFe` para gravar alguns campos no banco de dados.

Porém, surgiu uma dúvida, o XSD que usei originalmente vai ser alterado e consequentemente a classe gerada também.

O que seria correto, criar uma nova classe a partir desta nova versão do XSD ou alterar a existente para ficar em conformidade com o novo XSD?

Comment: Aconselho a criar uma nova classe e trabalhar com versionamento, assim como a NF-e também é versionada (com validade).

Comment: Nesse caso, acredito que você necessite ter um mapeamento entre o arquivo e uma classe para que vc possa manipular seus dados e atualizar a base. Sendo assim, toda vez que o arquivo mudar, você precisaria ter uma classe para representa-la.